# Pasarela de pago con Stripe

Tags: php, stripe

Actualmente estoy tratando de desarrollar una pasarela de pago con Stripe en PHP sin embargo no logro entender que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, en PHP tengo esto

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51Hcv***');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://midominio.com/';
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'unit_amount' => 2000,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);
echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
```

Basado en el codigo de la documentacion de Stripe https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

En el HTML tengo

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
            <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/btn-pagar.css">
            <div class="pagar" style="display:none; margin-top: 10px;">
                <button class="btn-pagar" id="checkout-button"><a href="sesion.php">Pagar</a></button>
            </div>
        
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51Hcv37L6gSe4N****");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("/sesion.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Ahora pese a que lo tengo casi igual al original del ejemplo en la documentación no me funciona para nada, al inicio pensé que era porque estaba en local, pero lo intente en el servidor y tampoco me funcionaba, simplemente me da error 500 cuando redirecciona al PHP... Por ahora esta todo estático porque no entiendo porque no me funciona.

Comment: Puedes dar más detalle sobre el error 500?

Comment: También te recomiendo redactar el API key que incluíste (puedes poner algo como `sk_test_***`)

Comment: El Error 500 es solo un error 500 osea no da motivos, y aunque utilice  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); y aun asi no puestra mas detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es difícil determinar cuál es el problema sin tener más datos sobre el error.

Por mientras, puedes bajar un sample de Checkout [acá](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments), o bajarlo con el Stripe CLI corriendo:

```
stripe samples create checkout-one-time-payments
```

y luego siguiendo [estas instrucciones](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/tree/master/server/php).

Comment: Y si a mi no me abre localhost:4242? me da error

Comment: Qué error te da? Corriste ya `composer install` y `php -S localhost:4242`? Tienes algun error en los logs del servidor?

Comment: Lo de php -S localhost:4242 no lo he corrido ? me podrias indicar donde se debe correr ? quizas ese es el problema

Comment: Sigue las instrucciones acá: https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/tree/master/server/php

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: Ya logre correr localhost:4242 pero me aparece Not Found
The requested resource / was not found on this server. donde debo colocar los archivos?

Comment: Cuál es el output al correr `php -S localhost:4242`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115327/discussion-between-maiker-leon-and-jlhonora).

Comment: una consuta ya logre la implementacion casi completa, sin embargo quisiera saber, si al realizar el pago mediante Stripe este puede devolverme una confirmación de que el pago ha sido realizado con exito en el PHP

Comment: Claro, indicando un `success_url` and `cancel_url` al crear la sesión. La URL correspondiente será llamada por Stripe cuando termine el proceso de compra. Más detalles acá: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo implemente